# I need help spacing text apart on a nav bar

Tags: html, css

So im making a nav bar in my project but the text on it are too close together beneath each other.
[image]

I tried changing text size but It now looks weird.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your code illustrating the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using an unordered list as `nav`, if so, you may add a `margin-bottom` to each list element, in the CSS, like so:

```
ul li{
margin-bottom: 20px
}
```